# HTML audio works with src, but not with <source>

Tags: html, angular, html5-audio

In my angular app I need to use the `<audio>` tag with the `<source>` element inside of it.
This works:

```
<audio [src]="path | secure | async"></audio>
```

This doesn't:

```
<audio>
   <source [src]="path | secure | async">
</audio>
```

I tried adding type, but got same results. I tried calling audio.load(). The source element in DOM has the source properly set, but audio won't play.

Comment: Try with `*ngIf` on audio tag, <audio *ngIf="path | async"><source .. ></audio>

Comment: I need to have <audio> present in DOM, there is some logic with custom buttons instead of native controls